# What type of differential equation is this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations

Need to find the general solution and characteristics, but I can't define type of this differential equation

$ u_{ttx}=u_{tx}^3 $

Comment: It is a nonlinear partial differential equation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation, but if I understand it correctly, couldn't you just write it as $dv/dt=v^3$?

Comment: @Peter_Tsrunchev  Notation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Notation

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: It is a nonlinear partial differential equation, first order in x, second order in t.